Execute a Database Update Operation and Non DB Function inside a Transaction (both-or-none) in Spring Boot
I have a database record update and a Kafka message push, which should be executed in an all-or-none way.
 public int UpdateRecord();
 public int puahMessageToKafka();

The scenario is,
The deployed Server getting failed after updating the database record (before pushing the message to Kafka) for some external reason (Etc: Kubernetes Pod crashes).
I need the database record update rollbacked in a case like this.
Spring boot annotations like @Transactional will not work in this case. Because it supports only for database related operations.
What would be the best way to handle this?

You probably need to use an old-school JDBC try catch with a DB rollback in the catch. If you are allowed to drop to JDBC let me know and I will answer.

@JohnWilliams We're using Spring Boot JdbcTemplate to connect to the database.

It seems Spring for Apache Kafka also supports transactions, along with database updates. It allows the capability to rollback Kafka messages, where the Consumer won't read the rollbacked Kafka messages.
 @Transactional
 public void test(){
    UpdateRecord();
    puahMessageToKafka();
 }

By implementing something like above (with some other config changes), it will make sure both database update and the Kafka message will be committed in a all-or-none manner.
